# float n decimal places in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ruby only returns the first 17 decimal places when dividing using a floating point number.

`1 / 13.to_f => 0.07692307692307693`

Is it possible to return more decimal places?

For instance, how would I find the 100'th decimal place of `22 / 7`?

Comment: Note that `pi != 22/7`; they diverge after the second decimal place. Also, `22/7`, repeats after six digits.

Comment: I don't think Ruby's floats have nearly that much precision. If you are going to be dividing numbers that won't repeat before whichever place you want to show (say, 100th), you should use Rational or BigDecimal.

Comment: I had assumed Rational or BigDecimal would have the capability to do what you want; however, after looking into them, it appears they don't.

Comment: Use `355.to_f/113 # => 3.1415929203539825`. It's more accurate than `22.to_f/7 # => 3.142857142857143`. `4 * Math::atan(1)
# => 3.141592653589793` is the best though. We'd use the first and last in interpreted BASIC "back in the day"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using multiplication, though it's not the most elegant solution.

```
a = 22
b = 7
nth_decimal = 100

a*(10**nth_decimal) / b
```

Comment: After looking at it, I don't know if BigDecimal can show that many places either. If you need to show out to that many places, this might be the simplest (or only) way. Just be sure to stick the decimal point in there if you're going to be displaying it (e.g. using `(a*(10**nth_decimal) / b).to_s.insert(-nth_decimal-1, ".")`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ruby's BigDecimal.

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

value = BigDecimal.new('22') / BigDecimal.new('7')
```

[RubyDocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that, too, and you'll have to forgive me for being new at this, but how do I format that to a string or array (the first little bit of it)?

Comment: obviously .to_i and .to_f both format it, but again, I would want the nth decimal.

Comment: You should be able to get that by indexing the correct value in `to_s`